# Let $f_n(x)$ be a sequence of integrable functions such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int^a_b |f_n(x)|dx=0$. Prove the following

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

If $g$ is an integrable function then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int^a_b g(x)|f_n(x)|dx=0$$

Ideas : Intuitively, it is somewhat obvious, but I don't know how to show it.. essentially, the function we must integrate is the product of two integrable functions, so it is integrable.

Then it suffices to calculate the limit of the infimum of the Upper Riemann Sum (or the limit of the supremum of the Lower Riemann sum), and show that it must equal 0. But I don't know how to show this.. I'll have to use what it means for a sequence to converge along with the fact that $g$ is integrable and $f_n$ is integrable, but I don't know how to bring these pieces together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about Riemann integrals: Since $g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, so $M:=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|g(x)|<\infty$, and hence 
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}|g(x)|\cdot|f_{n}(x)|dx\leq M\int_{a}^{b}|f_{n}(x)|dx,
\end{align*}
now use Squeeze Theorem to conclude:

Let $u_{n}=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}|g(x)|\cdot|f_{n}(x)|dx$ and $v_{n}=M\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}|f_{n}(x)|dx$, then $0\leq u_{n}\leq v_{n}$ and $v_{n}\rightarrow 0$. But $0\rightarrow 0$, so $u_{n}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: How do you prove the inequality? Also, doesn't this only tell us about $|g(x)|$?

Comment: $|g(x)|\cdot|f_{n}(x)|\leq M|f_{n}(x)|$, taking integrals both sides we have that.

Comment: Agh.. I feel so silly. I forgot that we can take the constant out of the integral.. Also, does this mean the absolute values around $f_n(x)$ are unnecessary? Like, even if we had the limit of the integral of $f_n(x)$ converging to 0, would the same conclusion follow?

Comment: We need absolute value, if not, Squeeze Theorem does not work.

Comment: I don't understand then.. how are we using squeeze theorem here if we only have that the integral is bounded above?

Comment: You may take a look now.

Comment: Thanks. For the last step, we note that $-|g| <= g <= |g|$, so $g(x)f_n(x)$ is also squeezed to 0, right?

Comment: Yes, you can perform like that.